# AsyncStorage.getItem return undefined when Debug JS Remotely is turned off -- React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I am having a problem so weird with AsycnStorage. I am trying to sent 4 requests with an Authentication token which is saved on AsycnStorage, the problem is that I am getting the token just once, in the first request works fine but in the second request the AsycnStorage return undefined as value. It is weird because **It only happens when the Debug JS Remotely is turned off**, if I test it with Debug JS Remotely is turned on that works fine. Also it happening just on iOS, on Android works fine with Debug JS Remotely is turned on and turned off.

```
export async function fetchApi(endPoint, payload = {}, method = 'get', headers = {}){
const accessToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
console.log(accessToken); 
return fetchival(`${apiConfig.url}${endPoint}`, {
    headers: _.pickBy({
        ...(accessToken ? {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
        } : {}),
        ...headers,
    }, item => !_.isEmpty(item)),
})[method.toLowerCase()](payload)
.catch((e) => {
    if (e.response && e.response.json) {
        e.response.json().then((json) => {
            if (json) throw json;
            throw e;
        });
    } else {
        throw e;
    }
});
```

};

This code works on :

Android with Debug JS Remotely turned on

Android with Debug JS Remotely turned off 

iOS with Debug JS Remotely turned on

Comment: what is the error that you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, my problem was that some requests didn't finish on ' / ' for instance I was hitting to `api/{id_user}/posts` instance of `api/{id_user}/posts/`.